# Android Web Applications Update

Tags: java, android, web-services

Is there any client like (File-Zilla in PHP) for android to update android application.

I am creating an android application for a job portal and i want that updates are received to users on daily basis.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way to this, is to create a app engine, such app engine from google, you can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1), is the best possible way, since is free, and you can create the cloud engine in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Funny! I'm also currently building an Android app as a client for a job portal. If you need to fetch frequent updates from your web-service about the latest job updates you need to build a way to communicate between the device and the web-service.

Some things you'll need to look into to build such an app are:

- You must make sure that you have a web-service that is providing service to your app on the server side. This web-service will be responsible for validating log-in, querying the database for new jobs and fetching them. (The web developers who built the job portal's website can assist you with this.)
- Decide on the format of data you want to exchange between the web-service and the device, such that they're compatible with each side. Look into JSON (which is light weight and preferable for mobile devices) and SOAP (which exchanges data in XML structure).
- Next you'll need to send and receive these messages via HTTP over the web to and from your web-service. Java has libraries for HTTP requests, you'll need to know.
- Finally either build your own JSON parser or, use the ksoap2 library (which is a third party library  in Java) for SOAP, for the app to parse messages on client side, i.e the device.
- Some things you'll need to take into consideration are network latency, update frequency etc issues which can be handled with multithreading the android app and proper planning. (You might want to skim through any introductory book on Distributed Systems to get an idea of real world challenges of such a system.)

Here is a link to give you a brief idea and get you started -

[A small SOAP communication Tutorial  for Android.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap)

**Update:**

Look into using libraries like [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) to make Http GET and POST operations to a web server and consume [RESTful web services](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html) which use JSON the standard data format for web communication.